# Creating Augmented Reality in Codename One Now

Tags: codenameone

I am thinking of using Codename One to develop an augmented reality app. Is it currently possible to develop an augmented reality app in Codename One with its current features?

Answer (score 0):

In theory yes. In practice I wouldn't recommend it right now.

We support z-ordering of native widgets which would allow you to implement AR on a technical level.

However, we don't offer any of the underlying native API's for AR and don't have any immediate plans to do so. This might change in the future but right now it's not ready.